# How to add custom property for a document in Alfresco

Tags: java, properties, alfresco, document

Is there a way to add custom properties to attached document in runtime ?

*For example*, consider there is a starting form with standard attach document control. Form has it business-related elements ( some checkbox and some textfields for example ). After user decides to start workflow ( or finish task if the form is not the very first one in a workflow ) there is a need **to associate form's element's values with attached document** for further processing.... Is it possible with Alfresco ? I event don't know where to dig and enquiry...

Thank you very mush for your time!

Best Regards,
Serge

Comment: Is your question how to save the property in general (can be done easily in Java for example), or how to save it in a specific UI?

Comment: It seems like you want to save workflow task properties on document(attached with that workflow). is that the case?

Comment: @Gagravarr my question is about how to attach property to a document attached to workflow ( packageItem )

Comment: @mitpatoliya exactly !

Answer (score 0):

For attaching additional properties at runtime you can use aspect in alfresco.Aspect can be added and removed at run time based on requirement.A document can have more than one aspect.
For development find below things.

1.Check what is an aspect and how to create it.(Aspect will ahve set of properties which you want to add).

2.Attach it in whatever stage you want it.

Comment: Thanks for anwer ! Will it be possible to search for document by those properties ( from attached aspect )

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to save workflow task properties on document(). So, to pass on properties related to workflow to document attached in workflow you have two options.

1. Through Alfresco javascript in workflow definition file. Here you need to access bpm_package from execution context and then using that you can access attached documents.
2. Through Task Listener class in workflow.

   - Checkout [this](http://blog.arvixe.com/create-listener-class-in-activiti-workflow-of-alfresco/) to know how to add listener class in workflow.
   - To know how to access attached documents [check this.](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/cant-access-bpmpackage-childrens-executionlistener-11052014)
   - Once you have access to attached document you can set properties on
     that using nodeservice apis.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems like very useful info - 'll definitely try this out !